# Copy of Source folder (prompt to input the folder name everytime) to Destination folder (prompt to input the folder name everytime)

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a simple batch script that can copy files from source folder (prompt to input the folder name everytime) to Destination folder (prompt to input the folder name everytime) and copy only those files inside source folder with latest current date. Is it possible to do so? Please help

Comment: And what have you tried so far and what errors did you encounter?

Comment: I have tried created a batch script as below, but not working.

Comment: @ECHO OFF

SET SOURCE=C:\Deployment\Bulid
SET DESTINATION=C:\Deployment\Bulid
SET LOGDIR=C:\For_UAT_Deployment\Log
For %%i IN (%LOGDIR%") DO IF NOT EXIST %%~si\NUL (
 MD "%LOGDIR%"
)

SET SOURCE_ID=
ECHO Enter Source folder Name
SET /P SOURCE_ID=:
IF '%SOURCE_ID%'=='' (
 ECHO ### Error - Blank value not allowed ###
 GOTO END
)
For %%i IN ("%SOURCE%\%SOURCE_ID%") DO IF NOT EXIST %%~SI\NUL (
 ECHO ### Error - Folder [%SOURCE%\%SOURCE_ID%] does not exist ###
 GOTO END
)

Comment: for /F "tokens=2-4* delims=/ " %%A in ('DATE/T') do set MMDDYY=%%A-%%B-%%C

xcopy "%SOURCE%\%SOURCE_ID%\bin" %DESTINATION%\%DESTINATION_ID%\bin /E /Y /D:%MMDDYY%

Answer (score 0):

The relevant commands would be

```
set /p "var=prompt"
```

which accepts input from the keyboard to `var` after prompting with *prompt*

and

```
xcopy /d "%var1%\*" "%var2%\"
```

where `var1` and `var2` are environment variables containing your strings - they are quoted to ensure that spaces (etc) in directory names are processed correctly.

From the prompt, try

```
set /?
```

and

```
xcopy /?
```

for more information and options.

Comment: SET SOURCE_ID=
ECHO Enter Source folder Name
SET /P SOURCE_ID=:"var=prompt"
IF '%SOURCE_ID%'=='' (
 ECHO ### Error - Blank value not allowed ###
 GOTO END

Comment: sorry, i am totally blur on programming

Comment: @ECHO OFF
for /F "tokens=2-4* delims=/ " %%A in ('DATE/T') do set MMDDYY=%%A-%%B-%%C

SET SOURCE=C:\Deployment\Bulid
SET DESTINATION=C:\Deployment\Bulid
SET LOGDIR=C:\For_UAT_Deployment\Log
For %%i IN (%LOGDIR%") DO IF NOT EXIST %%~si\NUL (
 MD "%LOGDIR%"
)

SET SOURCE_ID=
ECHO Enter Source folder Name
SET /P "var=prompt" SOURCE_ID=:
IF '%SOURCE_ID%'=='' (
 ECHO ### Error - Blank value not allowed ###
 GOTO END
)
For %%i IN ("%SOURCE%\%SOURCE_ID%") DO IF NOT EXIST %%~SI\NUL (
 ECHO ### Error - Folder [%SOURCE%\%SOURCE_ID%] does not exist ###
 GOTO END
)

Comment: SET DESTINATION_ID=
ECHO Enter Destination folder Name
SET /P "var=prompt" DESTINATION_ID=:
IF '%DESTINATION_ID%'=='' (
 ECHO ### Error - Blank value not allowed ###
 GOTO END
)
For %%i IN ("%DESTINATION%\%DESTINATION_ID%") DO IF NOT EXIST %%~SI\NUL (
 ECHO ### Error - Folder [%DESTINATION%\%DESTINATION_ID%] does not exist ###
 GOTO END
)

xcopy "%SOURCE%\%SOURCE_ID%\bin" %DESTINATION%\%DESTINATION_ID%\bin /E /Y /D:%MMDDYY%

Comment: This is current the script that I have

Answer (score 0):

I use script as below and it is working now. But is it possible to save a log of what files been copy over?

```
@ECHO off
for /F "tokens=2-4* delims=/ " %%A in ('DATE/T') do set MMDDYY=%%A-%%B-%%C

SET /p var1="Source="
SET /p var2="Destination="

xcopy /d "%var1%\bin" %var2%\bin /E /Y %DDMMYY%
```

Comment: Try appending ` >>logfilename.txt` to the `xcopy` line.